# Proxmox IP is already in use (by pve itself)

Tags: networking, virtualization, proxmox

I've run into a problem adding IP's to an SME server VM.

> Determining if ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.xx is already in use for device eth3... 
>   Error, some other host(mac address) aleady uses address xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.

Now, of course, I started looking at other servers hosted in Proxmox and outside of it as well, finding no other device using the IP addresses in question.

You could ping one of the addresses, but not the other.
More precisely I could ping the local address, but not the public one.

I realised that the device using the IP's is actually Proxmox itself. When I disabled the interfaces in the host (`ifdown vmbr6`) I could assign the address to the server in question after that.

The IP's are configured like this in the Proxmox network tab.

```
vmbr6 Linux Bridge enp5s0f0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 255.255.255.0
```

Now I might add that the SME server is being migrated using this guide:
https://www.caretech.io/2017/10/17/migrating-virtualbox-vdi-to-proxmox-ve-5/

Though I don't think it's related to the networking issue.

So steps that I've taken to try and fix the issue are:

1. Rebooted the SME server
2. Restarted the networking service on the SME server
3. Rebooted Proxmox
4. Removed network interfaces from the SME server
5. Changed the interface model from VirtIO to IntelE1000
6. Tried changing the MAC addresses

I've been battling this issue for 2 days and any and all help would be appreciated. Kind of in a hurry to migrate our services from VirtualBox to Proxmox.

Thank you.

Comment: I removed the interfaces from Proxmox as well, but they still says that the IP is already in use, even though you can't even see it as an adapter on the Proxmox host. Before you say that then something else is using it, stopping Proxmox from running also makes the IP unpingable.

Comment: Alright, so even though it doesn't really make sense, I tried to run another VM with the same adapters... and it seems to work. I'm not sure how that works to be honest. Seems like it's more of a problem with the SME server software, rather than Proxmox.

Comment: Moving the SME server from VM to Proxmox using an image instead of SME's own migration solution Affa is most likely the cause of the problem. Though personally I don't like using Affa, but seems like I have no choice right now. I'll try it out and see if that works. If anyone has an idea how to fix the networking problem without having to resort to Affa, any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Okay, maybe it wasn't the problem of using an "unofficial" way of moving an SME server, since setting up a new SME server seems to have given the same result. Now I'm out of ideas.